# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer Deadly Signal Error no idea what to do

Tags: c++

```cpp
std::vector<int> deleteNth(std::vector<int> arr, int n)
{
  std::vector<int> arr2 = arr;
  std::vector<int> positionstodelete;
  unsigned short counter;
  unsigned short lengthofmotives = arr.size();
  unsigned short currentnumber;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < lengthofmotives-1; i++){
counter = 1;
    currentnumber = i;
    
    for(int i = currentnumber; i < lengthofmotives-1;i++){
      if (arr2[currentnumber] == arr2[i+1]){
counter++;
  if(counter > n){
  positionstodelete.push_back(i+1);
    counter--;
  }
      }
    }
    
  }
  size_t postodelsize = positionstodelete.size();
  counter = 0;
  if (postodelsize > 0){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < postodelsize;i++){
    arr2.erase(arr2.begin() + positionstodelete[i]);
    counter++;
  }
    }
 
  return arr2;
}
```

when i run this code in codewars i get this error

STDERR "
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==1==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x0000016d8000 (pc 0x7fe790e16cf1 bp
0x0000016ca390 sp 0x7ffe0cacc418 T1)

==1==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.

==1==WARNING: invalid path to external symbolizer!

==1==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!

#0 0x7fe790e16cf0  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x18ecf0)

#1 0x4258bd  (/workspace/test+0x4258bd)

#2 0x4284a8  (/workspace/test+0x4284a8)

3 0x426aae  (/workspace/test+0x426aae)

#4 0x4264dd  (/workspace/test+0x4264dd)

#5 0x4261cb  (/workspace/test+0x4261cb)

6 0x42c8d5  (/workspace/test+0x42c8d5)

#7 0x4259bd  (/workspace/test+0x4259bd)

#8 0x7fe790ca9bf6  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)

#9 0x4046f9  (/workspace/test+0x4046f9)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.

==1==ABORTING"

what does it mean? When i run my code in dev c++ it runs fine and does the calculations correctly, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Use the undefined behaviour sanitizer when developing your program. Add `-fsanitize=undefined` to the compilation flags in your *debug* build and see what happens.

Comment: The code is from https://www.codewars.com/kata/554ca54ffa7d91b236000023/train/cpp

Comment: However, for an easy way to see what is wrong with the program, quickly analyze a boundary condition. Say you need to delete *all* members. What is the contents of the positions array? What is the last position? What is the size of arr2 at tge time you want to delete the last position?

Comment: idk nothing i try works

Answer (score 1):

`positionstodelete` constrains indexes of the vector arr2 before any erase. All indexes
in `positionstodeletee` after `arr2.erase(arr2.begin() + positionstodelete[i])` are invalidated, the size of arr2 changed. The message reports that your are trying to access the vector by an index out of bound.

You should replace the last loop with a reversed loop.

Comment: for(int i = postodelsize; i > 0; i--){
    arr2.erase(arr2.begin() + positionstodelete[i]);} doesn't work

Comment: Because you made the same error but with another array now. How did you get `int i = postodelsize` from `i < postodelsize` and `i > 0` from `int i = 0`? You need to read some C++ book.